# cannot get error message on build flutter web

Tags: flutter

I am trying to get the error message of exceptions when the web app is build.

I am able to get the error message when I run the app not when I build and run the app via docker

what I want is to capture the error when the app is running via docker like when the app is running via android studio

code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runZonedGuarded(() async {
    FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) {
      FlutterError.presentError(details);
      print('FlutterError.onError:\n$details\n_____');
    };

    PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError = (Object error, StackTrace stack) {
      print('PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError:\n$error\n$stack\n_____');
      return true;
    };

    runApp(const MyApp());
  }, (Object error, StackTrace stack) async {
    print('runZonedGuarded:\n$error\n$stack\n_____');
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
          seedColor: const Color(0xff0000ff),
          background: const Color(0xff3f456f),
          primary: const Color(0xffaebdd0),
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
        ),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'web exception test',
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 20,
              ),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  throw 'custom error';
                },
                child: const Text('raise exception'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

nginx.conf:

```
# on alpine, copy to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
user                            root;
worker_processes                auto;

error_log                       /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

events {
    worker_connections          1024;
}

http {
    include                     /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    sendfile                    off;
    access_log                  off;
    keepalive_timeout           3000;
    server {
        listen                  8080;
        root                    /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index                   index.html;
        server_name             localhost;
        client_max_body_size    16m;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$query_string;
        }
    }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
#Stage 1 - Install dependencies and build the app
FROM dart:3.1.0 as build-env

ARG 2.4.1

RUN apt-get update --quiet --yes
RUN apt-get install --quiet --yes \
    unzip \
    apt-utils

RUN dart pub global activate fvm 2.4.1
RUN fvm install 3.13.1
RUN fvm global 3.13.1
ENV PATH="/root/fvm/default/bin:${PATH}"
# Run flutter doctor
RUN flutter doctor -v
# Enable flutter web
RUN flutter config --enable-web

# Copy files to container and build
RUN mkdir /app/
COPY . /app/
WORKDIR /app/
RUN flutter pub get
RUN flutter build web --source-maps

# Stage 2 - Create the run-time image
FROM nginx:1.21.1-alpine
COPY --from=build-env /app/build/web /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 8080
```

running via android studio

[running via android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnL0t.png)

running via docker:

[running via docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLKSv.png)